# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crispy_forms'

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

django-crispy-forms is present in requirements.txt (added using pip freeze > requirements.txt)
**requirements.txt**

```
asgiref==3.2.10
autopep8==1.5.4
beautifulsoup4==4.9.1
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
Django==3.1
django-crispy-forms==1.9.2
feedparser==5.2.1
idna==2.10
Pillow==7.2.0
pycodestyle==2.6.0
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.24.0
six==1.15.0
soupsieve==2.0.1
sqlparse==0.3.1
toml==0.10.1
urllib3==1.25.10
```

**heroku run pip freeze**

```
appdirs==1.4.4
asgiref==3.2.10
certifi==2020.6.20
distlib==0.3.1
Django==3.1.1
filelock==3.0.12
gunicorn==20.0.4
pipenv==2018.5.18
pytz==2020.1
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
virtualenv==20.0.31
virtualenv-clone==0.5.4
whitenoise==5.2.0
```

So, this leads to Application Error on heroku deploy and the `heroku logs --tail` gives `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crispy_forms'`

Comment: notice that the error gives you a value of `crispy_forms`, not `django-crispy-forms`. I bet this why you have this error. If that doesn't work, please send some message

Comment: Make sure you've committed and pushed your changes to `requirements.txt`.

Comment: @zot8 is there any way to make it right?

Comment: @Alasdair Yes, changes are committed and pushed.

Comment: @zot8 you *do* import [`crispy_forms`](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/tree/master/crispy_forms)

Comment: yeah, I understand that, but that's not an `ImportError`, it's a `ModuleNotFoundError`.
@HemaChandran, can you run `heroku run pip freeze` again to see what's really installed on Heroku? Also, maybe you need to run some migrations again. Just follow the steps you've done before, and make sure you're pushing the right `requirements.txt` file.

Comment: Just now updated the requirements.txt and pushed both origin and heroku. But the problem still continues

Comment: did  you tried    heroku  run  pip install django-crispy-forms    ? manually . Hope so it will fix problem @HemaChandran

Comment: Yeah, I did @gamer

Answer (score 0):

// Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64922610/1965726

I had the same error. I had to put `"crispy_forms"` in double-quotes and then try to re-import with `pip install django-crispy-forms`. This solved it for me.

It turns out the first time I did a 'pip install' I was not in my (env) virtual environment, so I assumed I had installed it successfully.

pip freeze > requirements.txt:

```
asgiref==3.3.1
Django==3.1.3
django-crispy-forms==1.10.0
pkg-resources==0.0.0
pytz==2020.4
sqlparse==0.4.1
```

Answer (score -1):

Install with pipversion. Like, "pip(pythonversion) install --user whichpackagewant"